# How to escape Javascript code that is echoed in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, escaping

I have this code that is captured in the jquery Data object from a php page.

```
echo "
    var $d = $('<div/>', {
        id: 'hi' + $('#textResp').children().length,
        class: 'eventdiv',
        html: 'hello'
    }).hide().fadeIn(3000);

    $('#textResp').append($d)

";
```

Problem is, the 's are not escaped. I have tried using /' to escape, but it comes up with an error. I am sure I am doing this wrong, does anyone know where to put the /' instead of '?

Comment: Wait, why would it error at all? You've got ' inside of ", it shouldn't do anything...

Comment: Horrible things are probably happening because PHP is interpolating all those $ signs as PHP variables, which would completely screw up your output.  Echo using single quotes.  The easiest and safest way to put PHP variables in there is to use `json_encode`, in my experience.

Comment: Why nobody suggests `?> whatever <?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [php nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead of quotes at all which would simplify things:

```
echo <<<'DOC'
    var $d = $('<div/>', {
        id: 'hi' + $('#textResp').children().length,
        class: 'eventdiv',
        html: 'hello'
    }).hide().fadeIn(3000);

    $('#textResp').append($d)
DOC;
```

then use whatever you want inside (quote or dquote).  This is, of course, unparsed so if $d was actually referring to a php var then you would have problems.

Comment: NOWDOCs are such an underused PHP feature

Answer (score 1):

Your apostrophes actually look fine. But, within a double quoted string, PHP will evaluate any string beginning with a dollar sign as a variable and not produce the desired result. Try replace the jquery related instances of `$` with `\$`. Like this:

```
echo "
    var \$d = \$('<div/>', {
        id: 'hi' + \$('#textResp').children().length,
        class: 'eventdiv',
        html: 'hello'
    }).hide().fadeIn(3000);

    \$('#textResp').append(\$d)

";
```

Comment: 2nd line: `var $d =`  Looks like it's a jQuery var :P

Comment: @jnpcl: How can you be sure about that?

Comment: @Asaph: The context of the code. It makes no sense if you assume `$d` to be a PHP variable.

Comment: @jnpcl: I'm not convinced by that argument. `$d` is a pretty unconventional name for a javascript variable. If there is a PHP line somewhere above the code we see in the question that looks like this: `var $d = 'myvar';` than it works nicely. Nevertheless, I amended my answer just in case you are correct.

Comment: @Asaph: When using jQuery, naming a variable this way (`$d`) allows you to use jQuery functions on that variable a little easier: `$d.func()` rather than `$(d).func()`.  That seems to me like a MUCH more likely situation than having `$d` be a PHP variable used to dynamically name a javascript variable.

Comment: @jnpcl: Very well then. I didn't know about that feature in jquery. I changed my answer based on your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @jnpcl `$d` is a valid JS identifier for the variable/property named ... `$d` (it could very well be `var d = ...`). There is no "jQuery magic" and it does not *implicitly* mean `$(d)` (which evaluates `d` and uses it as an argument to the application of the function-object which [hopefully] results from the evaluation of `$`). However, the `$var` convention is discouraged in JavaScript and likely comes from using sigils in PHP/Perl. I do agree, however, that -- hopefully -- `$d` was not meant to be a PHP variable as that sort of "dynamic" code just sounds like a mess ;-)

Comment: @pst: Thanks for the explanation. After doing some testing, it seems that the situatons needing this naming method are fairly limited: **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SndRX/)**.  I suppose a better "reason" to use `var $d` rather than `var d` would be so you can tell the difference between a `$var` with jQuery content, and a regular `var`.

Answer (score 1):

use `json_encode` function in php, it behaves like the `escape_javascript` function in rails.

just pass a string argument to the `json_encode` function, and it return the escaped string for you, see the sample code below:

```
<?php
$form_html  = <<HTML
<form action='...' ...>
    <input type='...' name='...' ...>
    ...
</html>
HTML;
?>

var form_html = <?php echo json_encode($form_html); ?>;
$('.remote#create_form').html(form_html).slideDown();
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use `\` before all `'`s.

However, this is puzzling, why do you feel you need escape characters? It appears you are simply echoing this output, if this is between `<script />` tags, you should be fine.

Comment: Well it isn't, that's why I said in the second paragraph it shouldn't be needed.  But I was expressing to him that he had the escape character wrong and that it should be \.  I don't feel this is worth a down vote, considering I was the first to respond he should be using \ in some capacity.

Comment: Yes, but that came later. I didn't downvote, btw. and gave an offset ;-)

Answer (score -1):

PHP will attempt to expand variables, `$name`, that occur in strings wrapped in double quotes. Since `$d` looks like a variable to the PHP interpreter, it will try to replace it with the variable's value.

Assuming that you don't have `$d` defined anywhere, that will produce an empty space and, possibly, a notice (if you are using error level E_NOTICE).

To prevent that from happening, escape dollar signs with a backslash (replace `$` with `\$`)

Answer (score -1):

Use single quotes for your string construction. Only use double quotes when you specifically are including variables that you want evaluated. PHP is trying to evaluate all of those $ references you have in there. By using single quotes, you will avoid many escaping problems.

```
echo '
    var $d = $("<div/>", {
        id: "hi" + $("#textResp").children().length,
        class: "eventdiv",
        html: "hello"
    }).hide().fadeIn(3000);

    $("#textResp").append($d)

';
```